# How i can create simple condition for query mysql?

Tags: javascript, mysql

i have complex for handle request filtering . and i have

```
var p = payment , o = outlet, and m = member
```

and i need different condition for every single var.. like

```
p == 'all' && m =='all' && o =='all'
p == 'all' && m == 'all' && o != 'all'
p == 'all' && m != 'all' && o == 'all'
p == 'all' && m != 'all' && o != 'all'
p != 'all' && m == 'all' && o == 'all'
p != 'all' && m == 'all' && o != 'all'
p != 'all' && m != 'all' && o != 'all'
p != 'all' && m != 'all' && o == 'all'
```

because i want query for different condition , example

```
if(p == 'all' && m =='all' && o =='all'){
"select a,b,c,d from table"
}
if(p == 'all' && m == 'all' && o != 'all'){
 "select a,b,c,d from table where o=o"
}
```

can i create simple way ? because i think this is so ugly

Comment: I think what you have is good, otherwise it will result in a bunch of nested conditions!

Comment: How does the query depend on those variables? Can you show an example?

Comment: @PritamBanerjee should doing this for create query ? no one simple ways? :( . and i miss some condition ?

Comment: You need to show us at least some of your queries. I'm 99% sure there's a much faster way.

Comment: I always found something to the effect of `WHERE (X = 'all' OR t.x = X) AND (Y = 'all' OR t.y = Y)` rather succinct; and effective when the sql optimizer can be trusted. _Though I usually use NULL instead of 'ALL'._

Comment: Tip: Collect into an array all your conditions and values, then concatenate those conditions like `'o=?'` with `conditions.join(' AND ')` and bind the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```js
var params = {
  p: 'all',
  m: '2',
  o: '7'
};

var conds = Object.keys(params)
  .map(key => ({ name: key, value: params[key], isAll: params[key] == 'all' }))
  .filter(c => !c.isAll)
  .map(c => `\`${c.name}\` = '${c.value}'`)
  .join(" AND ");

var query = "SELECT FROM table" + (conds ? " WHERE " + conds : "");

console.log(query);
```

1. Start with a parameter object, turn it into an array of objects containing the key and value, plus the `all` test.
2. filter out `all`s
3. map to query part
4. join

Comment: this is exactly what i need . thanks Chris ! u save my day

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your logic. I'm assuming most of the code will remain the same, so you can do something like this:

```
var query = 'something'

if (p = 'all') {
   query = query + ' ... '
}

if (m = 'all') {
   query = query + ' ... '
}

if (o = 'all') {
   query = query + ' ... '
}
```

ps. It's not a good idea to set the actual query in javascript, due to sql injection, database column exposure etc. You best do this server side.

Comment: im using for node express